# Save raster tiles created by catalog_apply as single file

Tags: r, lidr

I have a big point cloud (3.5 GB) and want to create a big DTM from it using R. In the "old" `lidR` version this was possible by turning on `automerge = TRUE`. If the tiles could not be merged, a virtual raster was returned. If they could, a raster object was returned. I might be wrong, because I am new to the `terra` package, but this did not work for me anymore. I tried making my DTM with the following code:

```
# load data
ctg <- readTLSLAScatalog(ctg_path)

# set options
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(dtm_path, "/tile_{ID}")
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 20
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 5
opt_merge(ctg) <- TRUE

# my function
make_dtm <- function(chunk){ 
  las <- readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  las <- classify_ground(las, csf(class_threshold = 0.3, cloth_resolution = 0.1))
  dtm <- rasterize_terrain(las, res = 0.01, algorithm = tin())
  dtm <- crop(dtm, ext(chunk)) # remove buffer
  return(dtm)
}

# execution
dtm <- catalog_apply(ctg, make_dtm)
writeRaster(dtm, file.path(dtm_path, "final.tif"), overwrite = T)
```

But the return is always a list with the filenames. I guess I am just not up-to-date anymore on `lidR`, but how can I use `catalog_apply()` to obtain a `SpatRaster` which I can save as a single tif?

**Edit:**
The new working solution:

```
# load data
ctg <- readTLSLAScatalog(ctg_path, chunk_size = 20, chunk_buffer = 5)

# my functions
make_dtm <- function(chunk){ 
  las <- readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  las <- classify_ground(las, csf(class_threshold = 0.3, cloth_resolution = 0.3))
  dtm <- rasterize_terrain(las, res = 0.01, algorithm = tin())
  dtm <- crop(dtm, ext(chunk)) # remove buffer
  return(dtm)
}
make_dtm_ctg <- function(las) {
  options <- list(
    need_buffer = TRUE, # buffer necessary
    automerge = TRUE) # combine outputs
  output <- catalog_apply(las, make_dtm, .options = options)
  return(output)
}

# execution
dtm <- make_dtm_ctg(ctg)
writeRaster(dtm, file.path(dtm_path, "DTM.tif"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing changed on this aspect. The option auto-merge is still supported but you did not use it here.

```r
options = list(automerge = TRUE)
dtm <- catalog_apply(ctg, make_dtm, .options = options)
```

It is different from `opt_merge`. The idea is that `catalog_apply` is not intended to be used bare bone but is expected to be used inside a wrapper function. For example:

```r
make_dtm <- function(las){ 
  if (is(las, "LAS")) {
    las <- classify_ground(las, csf(class_threshold = 0.3, cloth_resolution = 0.1))
    dtm <- rasterize_terrain(las, res = 0.01, algorithm = tin())
    return(dtm)
  } else if (is(las, "LAScluster")) {
    las <- readLAS(chunk)
    if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
    dtm <- make_dtm(las)
    dtm <- crop(dtm, ext(chunk)) # remove buffer
    return(dtm)
  } else if (is(las, "LAScatalog")) {
    options = list(automerge = TRUE)
    dtm <- catalog_apply(ctg, make_dtm, .options = options)
    return(dtm)
  }
}
```

There are options for the developers who write the function and options for the users who use the function. Here you are the developer and with the options `automerge` you state *I want `catalog_apply` to automatically merge the chunks in a standard way*. If you do not add this options, the function will never do it, no mater what is in `opt_merge()` because if you do not use `automerge` we assume that your output is complex and cannot be automatically be merged with simple standard code so you must perform this task yourself. With `opt_merge()` you are on the user side and you state *I want do disable the `automerge` option to get a raw `list`*. `opt_merge()` is more for debugging purposes.

Also from lidR v4.0.0 you have `catalog_map()` that simplifies `catalog_apply()` for simple cases like your. Something like that should work.

```r
make_dtm <- function(las){ 
  if (is(las, "LAS")) {
    las <- classify_ground(las, csf(class_threshold = 0.3, cloth_resolution = 0.1))
    dtm <- rasterize_terrain(las, res = 0.01, algorithm = tin())
    return(dtm)
  } else if (is(las, "LAScatalog")) {
    dtm <- catalog_map(ctg, make_dtm)
    return(dtm)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware that the `opt_...()` options only work if explicitly included in the function. I always get confused whether to use `.options` or these `opt_...()`-functions...

Comment: Think this way: as the developer of the function how I want the function to behave (e.g. fail if buffer = 0, automerge, etc.), and as a user of the function what can I control (chunk size, buffer, parallelization, etc.)